# Illegal character in query when doing a conditional GET with multiple parameters

Tags: karate

While using Karate DSL version 0.9.2, I can send a conditional get with multiple parameters with no problem.

Something like 'Given path 'get?condition=payment_plan='B' and equal_paymnt_flg='D''', will work perfectly fine.

However on version 1.0.1 the same will produce an error, Illegal character in query at index 84, and the call will fail.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try 1.1.0.RC4 and if there is still a problem it can be a bug we need to fix.

More details here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1561